# Blob image from database to meta og:image

Tags: facebook, jsf, facebook-opengraph

have a medium blob data type on my database, it is storing pictures with gif,jpg,png,bmp types.

I am working on a JSF web project and I can retrieve the blob with no problem.

I am trying to retrieve the blob data from my database and try to insert it in a open graph image, this is for my facebook share functionality.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="blob from db image here"/>
```

But i am lost and i am not sure what to do, I don't think converting the blob to a base64 data using javascript is possible also.

Anyone can point me out to the right direction?

**UPDATED**

i guess converting blob to base64 data seems possible.

here's what i did:

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script>
        var base64;
        base64 = '#{testController.RenderLogo(item.logo)}';
        $('head').append('<meta property="og:image" content="data:image/png;base64,'+base64+'"/>');
    </script>
</h:head>
```

RenderLogo method:

```
public String RenderLogo(byte[] rawLogo) {
    String base64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(rawLogo);
    return base64String;
}
```

it works on some sharing site like ShareThis, but when sharing through facebook or twitter it gives me a `414 Request-URI Too Large`

any suggestions? :c

btw, i am using [ShareThis](http://www.sharethis.com/) in sharing through facebook / twitter.

Comment: Wow 9 years later and I have the same question. DOES NO ONE HAVE AN ANSWER haha